# Getting ClassCastException when gettting String from the Model class In GXT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am getting ClassCastException while getting the value from the Model.Please find the exception details below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.csscorp.presentation.spinneret.client.ams.AttendanceCaseCreationModel.getCheckinDate (AttendanceCaseCreationModel.java:164)
 at com.csscorp.presentation.spinneret.client.ams.AttendanceCaseCreationGridEditor$8.handleEvent   (AttendanceCaseCreationGridEditor.java:916)
```

Below is my code:

```
             ColumnConfig checkinDatecolumn = new ColumnConfig();
     checkinDatecolumn.setId("checkinDate");
     checkinDatecolumn.setHeader("Check In Date");
     checkinDatecolumn.setWidth(85);
     checkinDatecolumn.setMenuDisabled(true);
     checkinDatecolumn.setSortable(false);
    final DateField dateField1 = new DateField();
    dateField1.getPropertyEditor().setFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy")); 
     final String tempDate=dateField1.getRawValue();

    dateField1.getDatePicker().addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<DatePickerEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(DatePickerEvent dpe) {

        if(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getRosterDate()!=null){
        DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        rosterdate=format.parse(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getRosterDate());
            nextdate.setTime(rosterdate.getTime()+(1000*60*60*24));
            prevdate.setTime(rosterdate.getTime()-(1000*60*60*24));
        }
        int rowIndex = caseStoreModule.indexOf(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem());
        Window.alert("Row Index-->"+rowIndex);



    if(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate().toString() == null){//here I  am getting ClassCastException
                                            if (rosterdate.compareTo(dateField1.getValue())==0 || nextdate.compareTo(dateField1.getValue())==0){
                Window.alert("this is a valid date-->");
            }

            else {
                Window.alert("Enter a valid date-->");
                dateField1.reset();
            }



        }

        else{
//Here I need to Implement validation logic if the value from the model is not null

        }
            } 
    });
```

In model class I am setting the checkinDate as String and DTO also I am setting it as String only. But Why ClassCastException is coming. I am not getting the cause for this.

> Update

This is the line of AttendanceCaseCreationModel.java:164

```
163   public String getCheckinDate() {
164     

return get("checkinDate");

165 }
```

> Update

After calling toString method,ClassCastException is not coming.

```
return get("checkinDate").toString();
```

But When I check for null value,It's throwing the NullPointerException.

```
if(ACCCheckBoxModel.getSelectedItem().getCheckinDate() == null)
```

Exception details are below:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.csscorp.presentation.spinneret.client.ams.AttendanceCaseCreationModel.getCheckinDate(AttendanceCaseCreationModel.java:167)   at com.csscorp.presentation.spinneret.client.ams.AttendanceCaseCreationGridEditor$8.handleEvent(AttendanceCaseCreationGridEditor.java:920)

Comment: I think the problem in this line return get("checkinDate"); is I am getting the date from  the dateField and trying to return it as a String.Anyone who knows GXT well,Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.By below code change.

```
public String getCheckinDate() {

    if(get("checkinDate")==null)
            return null;
        else 
            return get("checkinDate").toString();


            }
```

Now it returns a String if it is not null.And null if it  is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public String getCheckinDate() 
{
   final Date date = (Date) get( "CheckinDate" );
   return date == null ? null : date.toString();
}
```

Remove the `toString()` from `getCheckinDate().toString()`.

Comment: Can you post the line 164 in AttendanceCaseCreationModel.java please.

Comment: Can you post the method definition of get("checkinDate") please.

Comment: that is the method from BaseModelData class

Comment: When you get( "checkinDate "), you should call the toString() then on it. Updated my answer.

Comment: let me try this.I think it should return String only.

Comment: Alternatively (and preferably) you should change the return type `String` to `Date`. You should then change the return to `return (Date) get("checkinDate")`.

Comment: thanks it works fine.But whenever it is null.I am getting nullpointer exception at the if condition which checks for null.How to resolve this.

Comment: What have you changed the code to? Please display your new `getCheckinDate()` and the `if` statement.

Comment: I updated my Question with the updated code.Please check

Comment: It's always returning null only.

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you update your question with your implementation of the method please.

Comment: please find my answer

Comment: Can you add your `getCheckinDate()` method definition. If it's the one in the answer you should change it so it reflects my method definition.